# Sonar javascript plugin issue

Tags: sonarqube

Currently, I am using the 1.3 javascript jar. In my code analysis, all the 3rd party files/folders are also being analyzed. I am thinking about upgrading to the new 2.1 javascript plugin. Will this fix the issue? I would like the sonar analysis to scan only the developers code and not the 3rd party code. Otherwise, the developer will just turn off the javascript analysis completely. I have looked at the [release notes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JavaScript+Plugin) but did not find anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup [exclusion patterns](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns) to prevent analysis of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: The link is broken because CodeHaus services have been terminated.

Comment: Thanks, updated the link to point to the current documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define sources files with `sonar.sources` and files excluded with `sonar.exclusions` property. For example, in javascript :

```
sonar: {
    sources: ['app','assets'].join(','),
    exclusions: ['**/app/dependencies/**', '**/assets/bower_components/**']
}
```